# Getting constraint error while collapsing Tableview section

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom cell view which contains an image and a label embedded in vertical Stack View.

Stack View is bound to 4 edges of Content View.

Image has constraint of 1:1 aspect.

Expand and collapse operations seem working fine however while I keep tapping, I see some warnings at some point and it seems random.

[image: cell]
[image: preview]
[image: expanded row]

```
2019-01-17 23:15:46.749683+0300 MyApp[10270:349316] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032e54a0 UIStackView:0x7f9f97d19620.height == 43.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032e5590 V:[UIStackView:0x7f9f97d19620]-(5)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9f97d19430 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032e5630 V:|-(5)-[UIStackView:0x7f9f97d19620]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9f97d19430 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032e5f40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9f97d19430.height == 499.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032e54a0 UIStackView:0x7f9f97d19620.height == 43.5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

What I run to expand/collapse is follows:

```
....
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "InboxTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "inboxCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
        tableView.reloadData()
....

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewData.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
            return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
        }else  {
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inboxCell", for: indexPath) as! InboxTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
                tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

            }else{
                tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what code you run in collapse/expand ?

Comment: lower the stack's bottom constraint to 999 and see if you still have that message in console

Comment: Do you have any height constraint for stackView? It doesn't seem like you have but maybe you set such a constraint in your code?

Comment: You have defined other constraints on the height of stackView and may be others. And they are incompatible. One way is to set a label (#01, #02, …) for all the constraints ; you will so easily identify the conflicting in the log.

Comment: @Sh_Khan lowering stack's bottom constraint didn't work

Comment: where the logic of collapse/expand ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I followed this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs 
logic is in didSelectRowAt I believe

Comment: @claude31 Thanks for advice. The label you mention is the identifier of contstraint, isn't it? I set identifier for constraints but I don't see them in the console view. Am I looking at the correct place?

Comment: @claude31 I think the reason I don't see them is those constraints in log are not set by me.

Comment: @Sh_Khan and should I concern this kind of warnings while app behavior is ok?

Comment: To set a label to constraints, I select the constraint in IB (easier to do it in objects list panel if you need to browse the whole list of constraints) and set identifier in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: thanks everyone for help. solved. the problem seems to be the header cell (section), not the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image's 1:1 aspect ratio constraint's priority to 999 or lower. It's forcing Auto Layout to generate a height constraint for the stack view in order to uphold the aspect ratio. That's bad for business.

Comment: thanks but didn't work, tried even removing constraint

Comment: Maybe set estimatedRowHeight to automatic or 0 as well. I'm grasping at straws too.

Comment: You may be close to the reason. I set it to 0 and alert showed up at the beginning of app.